# Weak convergence discrete space

Tags: probability, analysis

Let $X_n$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, and $X$ are random variables with at most
countably many integer values. Prove that that $X_n \to X$ weakly if and only if
$\lim_{n \to \infty} P (X_n = j) = P(X = j)$
for every $j$ in the state space of $X_n$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, and $X$.

I managed to prove one direction, i.e. if $X_n$ converges to $X$ weakly than the requirement holds. Would be grateful if you could give an advice how to prove the other direction:
assuming
$\lim_{n \to \infty} P (X_n = j) = P(X = j)$ for every $j$ in the state space of $X_n$, $n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, and $X$, then  $X_n \to X$ weakly.

Thanks.

Comment: Have the random variables _integer_ values? Otherwise, take $X_n=1/n$ and $X=0$: there is weak convergence, but $P(X_n=0)=0$ which doesn't converge to $P(X=0)=1$.

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't state it explicitly. The random variables take integer values. One can also state the problem a bit more generally: let $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ probability measures defined on some discrete space $X$ with countable many elements. Then $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly iff for every $x \in X$ holds: $\mu_n(\{ x\}) \to \mu(\{ x \})$.

Comment: What is the definition of weak convergence you have? (a good exercise is to check it for all the (equivalent) definitions)

Comment: Definition. $\mu_n \to \mu$ weakly if $\int fd\mu_n \to \int fd\mu$ for every continuous bounded function on the underlying space $X$.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is discrete then *every* function on $X$ is continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ a continuous bounded function, $p_{n,k}:=P(X_n=k)$ and $p_k:=P(X=k)$. If $f$ is continuous and bounded, then
$$\int f(X_n)dP=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{n,k}f(k)$$
(this makes sense as $f$ is bounded). Now the key point here is that $\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{n,k}=\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{k}=1$. More explicitely, fix a integer $R$. Denote $I_R:=\{k\in\mathbb Z, \left\lvert k\right\rvert \leqslant R\}$ and $J_R:=\{k\in\mathbb Z, \left\lvert k\right\rvert \gt R\}$. Then
$$\tag{*}\left\lvert \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{n,k}f(k)-\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{k}f(k)\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lvert \sum_{k\in I_R}p_{n,k}f(k)-\sum_{k\in I_R}p_{k}f(k)\right\rvert+\left\lvert \sum_{k\in J_R}p_{n,k}f(k)-\sum_{k\in J_R}p_{k}f(k)\right\rvert.$$
We control the last term in the following way:
\begin{align}
\left\lvert \sum_{k\in J_R}p_{n,k}f(k)-\sum_{k\in J_R}p_{k}f(k)\right\rvert&=\left\lvert \sum_{k\in J_R}\left(p_{n,k}-p_k\right)f(k) \right\rvert\\
&\leqslant \sum_{k\in J_R}\left\lvert p_{n,k}-p_k  \right\rvert \lvert f(k)\rvert\\
&\leqslant \lVert f\rVert_\infty \sum_{k\in J_R}  p_{n,k} +\lVert f\rVert_\infty \sum_{k\in J_R}  p_{n,k} \\
&=  \lVert f\rVert_\infty \left(1-\sum_{k\in I_R}  p_{n,k} \right)+\lVert f\rVert_\infty \left(1-\sum_{k\in I_R}  p_{k} \right).
\end{align}
Plugging this estimate into (*) and taking $\limsup_{n\to+\infty}$ gives
$$
\limsup_{n\to+\infty}\left\lvert \sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{n,k}f(k)-\sum_{k\in\Bbb Z}p_{k}f(k)\right\rvert\leqslant 2\lVert f\rVert_\infty \left(1-\sum_{k\in I_R}  p_{k} \right)
$$
and since $R$ is arbitrary, we get the result.

Comment: Thanks, Davide. I see, the key point I forgot here is the dominated convergence to conclude the series convergence.

Comment: May I ask f(X) is continuous on R, but the random variable is defined on a countable set, does this matter?

Comment: How do you apply DCT here? A bounded function on the integers need not be integrable w.r.t. the counting measure.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It seems that actually, the dominated convergence theorem may not work (a bounded function will be integrable since we work with probability measures, but we are not sure that $(\sup_n p_{n,k})_{k}$ is summable. I wrote an other argument.

Comment: There is a simpler argument. See my answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269483/dominated-convergence-theorem-applied-to-the-convergence-of-measures

Comment: First I am not sure there is a total order over arguments of proofs. Second the use of the dominated convergence theorem when we work on sum of series is actually reduces to a control of the tails, hence your approach is not fundamentally different from mine. Just that the splitting of the sum is hidden in the dominated convergence theorem.