# Dominated convergence theorem applied to the convergence of measures

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/249190/weak-convergence-discrete-space) there was used the dominated convergence theorem. However, I don't see how it works here. It was said that it can be used with respect to the counting measure because the function $f$ is bounded.

Let me restate my question in more general terms:

Let $M$ be a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ and $f$ be bounded and continuous. Let $(a(k))_{k\in M}$ and $(a_n (k) )_{k\in  M}$ be sequences of non-negative numbers for fixed $n$, such that $\sum_{k\in M} a_n (k) = 1, \sum_{k\in M} a(k) = 1$. Moreover, we assume that $a_n(k) \to a(k)$ for fixed $k\in M$. As I understood the answer above we then want to infer that
$$\sum_{k\in M} f(k) a_n (k) = \int_M g_n (k) \text d \chi (k) \to \int_M g (k) \text d \chi (k) = \sum_{k\in M} f(k) a (k)$$
where $g_n  (k) := f(k) a_n (k)$ and $g(k) := f(k)a(k)$, and $\chi $ denotes the counting measure.

However, the counting measure is not a finite measure, thus $\vert g  \vert \leq \vert f \vert$ is not useful here because $f$ is not integrable, though it is bounded. The integrability here comes from the sequences $a_n$ and $ a$. But how to make use of it?

Comment: The argument in the answer to the earlier post appears to be wrong and I have made a comment there.

Comment: A point that confused me was that in this context of weak convergence on discrete spaces I remember that I somebody gave the same argument (or at least an argument involving DCT) in a class I attended a few years ago.

Comment: DCT can be used but not in the form  it was used in that post. I have used DCT in my answer to give a proof.

Comment: I should point out one more thing here. In the earlier post $M$ was the set of positive integers and it was stated that weak convergence implies $P(X_n=j) \to P(X=j)$ for each $j$. For this part it is important that $M$ has no limit points. This becomes false if you just assume that $M$ is a countable set. Take $M=\{0,1,1/2,1/3,..\}$ $X_n =\frac 1 n,X=0$.

Comment: This is a fantastic comment! See, I have to prepare an exercise for some students, and the professor proposed me the characterization of weak convergence on discrete space. I think in his really precise formulation of his suggestion he forgot that $M$ must not have limit points. This was bothering me for at least half an hour, until I noticed what was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proof of weak convergence: $\sum (a(k)-a_n(k))^{+} \to 0$ by DCT because $0 \leq \left(a(k)-a_n(k)\right)^{+} \leq a_k$ and $\sum a_k =1<\infty$. But $\sum (a(k)-a_n(k))=1-1=0$ so we get $\sum (a(k)-a_n(k))^{-} \to 0$. [Because $x^{-}=x^{+}-x$]. Adding the two we get $\sum |a_n(k)-a(k)| \to 0$. It follows easily that $\sum_{k\leq j} (a_n(k)-a(k)) \to 0$ which means $P(X_n \leq j) \to P(X \leq j)$ for each $j$. So $X_n \to X$ weakly.

Comment: By $k\leq j$ do you mean $\{ k\in M : k \leq j \}$ , $j\in \Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes. I am taking $M$ to be the set of positive integers in this proof but that makes  difference.